# Unable to resolve force/lds from api/runtime/lwc-components/1.3.0-alpha/src/lightning/uiRecordApi/uiRecordApi.js

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

**HTML**

```
<template>
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact" onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
    <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <lightning-input-field field-name='Id' value={contactId}></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name='LastName'></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name='FirstName'></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name='Email'></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name='AccountId'></lightning-input-field>

        <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
            <lightning-button variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Create Contact">
            </lightning-button>
        </div>
    </div>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

**JS**

```
import {
LightningElement,
api,track
} from 'lwc';

export default class app extends LightningElement {
@track contactId;
handleSuccess(event) {
    this.contactId = event.detail.id;
}

}
```

Am getting following error when i ran the above code in Salesforce Play Ground. Since am new to salesforce, Can some one help me on this. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Playground does not support components like lightning-record-edit-form or any other base components that requires a Salesforce connection.

You will need to use an IDE like vscode extension for Salesforce and Salesforce CLI to connect your local machine to actual Salesforce org to verify and play with  components that require Salesforce UI API or Salesforce metadata API or Salesforce data.